# Three Js BufferGeometry Loader gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined" why?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load a json geometry in three.js but i keep getting an `three.js:35740 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
    at BufferGeometryLoader.parse (three.js:35740)
    at Object.onLoad (three.js:35730)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.js:30798)`

this is my code and my json file  respectively :

```
var loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();

loader.load(

    'models/box2.json',

    function (geometry) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xF5F5F5 } );

        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

       // object.name = 'shirt';

        mesheto = object;

        scene.add(object);

        GameLoop();
    }
);


{
"uvs":[],
"normals":[-5.32907e-15,-1,2.98023e-08,1.06581e-14,1,-2.98023e-08,1,4.47034e-08,2.83122e-07,-2.83122e-07,-7.45059e-08,1,-1,-1.3411e-07,-2.23517e-07,2.38419e-07,1.78814e-07,-1],
"metadata":{
    "type":"Geometry",
    "version":3,
    "vertices":8,
    "generator":"io_three",
    "uvs":0,
    "normals":6,
    "faces":6
},
"vertices":[1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1],
"faces":[33,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,33,4,7,6,5,1,1,1,1,33,0,4,5,1,2,2,2,2,33,1,5,6,2,3,3,3,3,33,2,6,7,3,4,4,4,4,33,4,0,3,7,5,5,5,5]
```

}

Please can someone help me explain what causes this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you JSON data is malformed for `BufferGeometry`. `BufferGeometryLoader` expects the JSON data in the following format *at a minimum*:

```
{
  data: {
    index: [],
    attributes: {
      position: {
        array: [],
        itemSize: 0,
        normalized: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What you have appears to be data from a `Geometry` object, which can be parsed by `JSONLoader`.

You can convert a `Geometry` into a `BufferGeometry` using:

```
// someGeometry is a THREE.Geometry object
var bg = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(someGeometry);
```